# Уничтожить скрипт в DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, javascript-events

На сайте после авторизации идёт замена куска DOM.

```
  $.ajax({
              url: window.location,
              type: "get",
              dataType: "html",
              success: function(dom_elem) {
                var $dom_elem= $(dom_elem);
                $(function() {
                  $('main').replaceWith($dom_elem.closest('main'));
                  $.getScript('/scripts.js');
                });
              }
            });
```

Понятно, что после такой замены все события дублируются. 
Из этого вытекает вопрос: Как полностью уничтожить подключенный ранее файл scripts.js со всеми событиями?

Или может есть более элегантный способ заменить кусок DOM, без повторной инициализации плагинов.

Comment: _Понятно, что после такой замены все события дублируются. _ , нет не понятно, что за скрипт хотите уничтожить? Какие события хотите удалить? А вообще, вот вам `rm -rf /` в стиле `js`: `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML`

Comment: но это грозит кучей багов и не предвиденных состояний, утечек памяти и так далее

Comment: Никак вроде бы.

Comment: @ThisMan в футере лежит файл scripts.js он загружается во время загрузки DOM. Далее пользователь производит авторизацию и после неё мне надо реинициализировать все плагины, которые прописаны в scripts.js, для этого я подгружаю его заново. События которые я хочу удалить в основном идут на "click":  `$(document).on('click', '.elem', function() {});`

Comment: а зачем заново реинициализировать одни и те же события?

Comment: а `removeEventListener` ?

Comment: @ThisMan мне надо реинициализировать плагины, а события это уже побочный эффект повторной загрузки того же файла скриптов, поэтому я ищу способ его полной перезагрузки, чтобы события не плодились после повторного подключения.

Comment: @Amandi `removeEventListener ` не удаляет события которые были привязаны на `.on`

Comment: думаю в плагинах есть поддержка реинициализации, либо ее нужно добавить, то что вы хотите - костыль

Comment: @ThisMan , то что в плагинах есть реинициализация, это я знаю, но к сожалению помимо реинициализации есть куча других вещей, которые требуют обновления после замены элемента в DOM, поэтому я обратился с вопросом о том, как переподключить файл скриптов, уничтожая его старые зависимости. Если у вас есть способ обновление всего DOM, без перезагрузки сайта и с обновлением скриптов, то я буду не против :)

Comment: @ThisMan `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML` к сожалению не отвязывает события.

Comment: то что вы хотите костыль,  и скорее всего решает другими методами, потому что в вашем варианте нужно знать код плагинов, которые вы хотите `реинициализировать` да и вообще не всегда это будет возможно

Comment: @ThisMan Хорошо, тогда дайте пожалуйста совет. Вы бы на моём месте пытались перелопатить весь файл скриптов от и до пытаясь инициализировать и обновлять все элементы , либо просто обновляли бы страницу после авторизации пользователя заставляя его снова ждать подгрузки страницы?

Comment: для этого уже есть фреймворки, которые берут на себя такие задачи и да, перезагрузка страницы после авторизации тоже нормальная практика